# How to sort a group of structures in C

Tags: c, sorting, struct

I made a 4 variables structures and assigned values just to `age`.

```
 struct database {
 int id_number;
 int age;
 float salary;
 };

 main()
 {
 struct database employee[4];
 struct database current; // Used later in my attempted sorting

 employee[1].age = 12;

 employee[2].age = 112;

 employee[3].age = 2;

 employee[4].age = 22;
```

I tried various ways to attempt to sort these but all failed,
for example:

```
 for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
 {
     current = employee[i];//"current" was previously assigned to the same type of struct
     j = i;

     while(employee[j-1].age > current.age)
     {
        employee[j] = employee[j-1];
        j = j-1;
     }
     employee[j] = current;
 }
```

Comment: In C, array indexes start at `0`. You have an invalid access with `employee[4].age = 22;` and `employee[0]` is never assigned anything before the loop.

Comment: Why not just use [qsort](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) ? It's a standard library function.

Comment: Also, `employee[j-1].age` too invokes a UB when `j = 0`

Comment: Have you looked at `man 3 qsort`? And write your own function that compares two structures by comparing their ages (or whatever you want). Specifically, see `void qsort_r(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void *, const void *, void *), void *arg);` You also need to be more specific. To say "all failed" isn't very much information if you're looking for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many errors, as pointed by others in comments.

(Out of bound array access, sorting algorithm is not correct, etc. )

---

For sorting array of `struct`, simplest way would be to use [***`qsort`***](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort)
where you need to define a custom comparator, something like following :

```
typedef struct database db;

int sort_by_age(void *a, void *b)
{
  db *_a = (db *)a;
  db *_b = (db *)b;

  if( _a->age > _b->age  ) return -1;
  if( _a->age == _b->age ) return 0;

  return 1;
}
```

And then use it like,

```
int no_of_employee = 4;

qsort( employee, no_of_employee, sizeof(db), sort_by_age );
```